# waypoints js Context applied incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

waypoints js Context applied incorrectly

Can you please check this example and tell me what is the problem its supposed that the small boxes background to be changed when come in view

http://goo.gl/rDpeQl

Comment: Use `$(this)` instead of `$('this')`

Answer (score 0):

Two bugs in you code:

1) use $(this) not $('this')

2) use background-color instead of backgroundColor

```
$(this).css("background-color", "#f99");
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/k40r2n4u/4/